# modificar tabla en mysql desde un formulario php trayendo los datos desde otro archivo

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas noches, estoy buscando ayuda con lo siguiente, quiero modificar un registro de una tabla en php, ya he conseguido como buscar buscar los registros y mostrar enlaces de modificar y eliminar mediante el siguiente codigo:

```
<!doctype html>
<?php

$texto = ''; 
//Variable que contendrá el número de resgistros encontrados 
$registros = ''; 
 if($_POST){ 
  $busquedanombre = trim($_POST['buscarnombre']); 
  $busquedaimo = trim($_POST['buscarimo']);
  $busquedasiglas = trim($_POST['buscarsiglas']);
  $busquedabandera = trim($_POST['buscarbandera']);
 $entero = 0;   

 mysql_set_charset('utf8'); 

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM buques WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%" .$busquedanombre. "%' AND IMO LIKE '%" .$busquedaimo."%' AND SIGLAS LIKE '%" .$busquedasiglas. "%' AND BANDERA LIKE '%" .$busquedabandera. "%'" ; 

 $resultado = mysql_query($sql);

 if (mysql_num_rows($resultado) > 0){ 
    $registros = '<p>Hemos encontrado ' . mysql_num_rows($resultado) . ' registros </p>';
    $texto .=  '<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 bordercolor=0e590d >';
        $texto .=  '<thead><tr><td width=210>Nombre del Buque</td><td width=65>IMO</td><td width=70>Siglas</td><td width=150>Bandera</td></tr></thead>';
    while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
      //$texto .=  '<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 bordercolor=0e590d >';
        $texto .=  '<tr><td width=210>'.$fila['NOMBRE'].'</td>'; ;
        $texto .= '<td width=65><font size ="3", color ="#095107">'.$fila['IMO'].'</font></td>';
        $texto .= '<td width=70>'.$fila['SIGLAS'].'</td>';
        $texto .= '<td width=150>'.$fila['BANDERA'].'</td>';
        $texto .=  '<td width=70><a href="modificar-buque.php?id='.$fila['IMO'].'">Modificar</a></td>';
        $texto .=  '<td width=25><a href="confirmar-eliminar-buque.php?id='.$fila['IMO'].'">Eliminar</a></td></tr>';
    }
    $texto .='</table>';
    }else{
      $texto = "No existen registros que coincidan con los parámetros de búsqueda.";
    }

 }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Buscar Buque</title>
  </head>
  <body>




    <form method="POST" action="" onSubmit="return validarForm(this)">

      <p>
        <label for="buscarnombre">Nombre del buque:</label>
        <input name="buscarnombre" type="search" id="buscarnombre">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="buscarimo">IMO:</label>
        <input type="number" name="buscarimo" id="buscarimo">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="buscarsiglas">Siglas:</label>
        <input type="search" name="buscarsiglas" id="buscarsiglas">
      </p>
      <p>
      <label for="buscarbandera">Bandera:</label>
      <select name="buscarbandera" id="buscarbandera">
        <option value=" "> Seleccione una Bandera </option>
        <option value=" Afganistán  "> Afganistán </option>
        <option value=" Akrotiri    "> Akrotiri </option>
        <option value=" Albania "> Albania </option>
        <option value=" Alemania    "> Alemania </option>
        bla bla bla lista de paises
      </select></p>
      <p>


        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">
      </p>

  </form>

  <?php  // Se muestran los resultados de la consulta, número de registros y contenido. 
   echo $registros; 
   echo $texto;  ?>
    <p><br>
    </p>
</body></html>
```

Presionando el enlace de modificar, enlazar a la siguiente pagina haciendo el enlace con el registro llevando el identificador IMO:

```
<!doctype html>
<?php

include('libreria/motor.php');
$v1 =$_GET['id'];
$v2 = $v1;

$query="select * from buques where IMO='$v2'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Agregar Buque</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form target="_self" autocomplete="on" method="post" action=""

      name="BUQUE"> <label for="NOMBRE">Nombre:</label> <br>
      <input autocomplete="on" maxlength="40" required name="NOMBRE" type="text" value="$row[NOMBRE]"><br>
      <label for="IMO">IMO:</label> <br>
      <input autocomplete="on" required name="IMO" type="number"><br>
      <label for="SIGLAS">Siglas IMO:</label><br>
      <input autocomplete="on" maxlength="10" required name="SIGLAS"type="text"><br>
      <label for="BANDERA">Bandera:</label><br>
      <select required name="BANDERA">
        <option value=" "> Seleccione una Bandera </option>
        <option value=" Afganistán  "> Afganistán </option>
        <option value=" Akrotiri    "> Akrotiri </option>
        <option value=" Albania "> Albania </option>
        <option value=" Alemania    "> Alemania </option>
        bla bla bla lista de paises
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="PUERTOREG">Puerto de Registro:</label> <br>
      <select required name="PUERTOREG">
        <option value=" "> Seleccione un puerto de registro </option>
        <option value=" Aachen  "> Aachen </option>
        <option value=" Aalesund    "> Aalesund </option>
        <option value=" Aarhus  "> Aarhus </option>
        <option value=" Abaco   "> Abaco </option>
        <option value=" Abakan  "> Abakan </option>
        <option value=" Abidjan "> Abidjan </option>
        bla bla lista de puertos
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="EMAIL">e-Mail:</label> <br>
      <input autocomplete="on" name="EMAIL" type="email"><br>
      <label for="ESLORA">Eslora (LOA):</label><br>
      <input autocomplete="on" required name="ESLORA" type="number" step="any"><br>
      <label for="PUNTAL">Puntal (Depth Moulded):</label><br>
      <input autocomplete="on" required name="PUNTAL" type="number" step="any"><br>
      <label for="MANGA">Manga (Breadth Moulded):</label><br>
      <input autocomplete="on" required name="MANGA" type="number" step="any"><br>
      <label for="ARMADOR">Armador:</label><br>
      <textarea required name="ARMADOR" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>
      <label for="OPERADOR">Operador:</label><br>
      <textarea required name="OPERADOR"></textarea><br>
      <label for="TONBRUTO">Tonelaje Bruto:</label> <br>
      <input autocomplete="on" required name="TONBRUTO" type="number" step="any"><br>
      <label for="TONNETO">Tonelaje Neto:</label><br>
      <input autocomplete="on" required name="TONNETO" type="number" step="any"><br>
      <label for="CAPCARGA">Capacidad de carga (m³):</label><br>
      <input autocomplete="on" required name="CAPCARGA" type="number" step="any"><br>
      <br>
      <input name="Enviar" id="Enviar" value="Enviar" type="submit"><br>
    </form>
    <p><br>
    </p>
</body></html>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que el formulario de modificación se traiga los datos del registro seleccionado y los muestre dentro del formulario, de modo que el usuario solo MODIFIQUE la informacion que necesita y luego presione enviar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ya lograste solucionar tu problema?

Comment: Si, muchas gracias, la respuesta de MRH era todo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lo que quiero hacer es que el formulario de modificación se traiga los
> datos del registro seleccionado y los muestre dentro del formulario,
> de modo que el usuario solo....

en tu archivo modificar-buque.php, cuando imprimas una etiqueta, por ejemplo:

```
<input autocomplete="on" maxlength="40" required name="NOMBRE" type="text" value="$row[NOMBRE]">
```

tienes que agregar la palabra "echo" en el value, de lo contrario no estas imprimiendo nada. Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
<input autocomplete="on" maxlength="40" required name="NOMBRE" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['NOMBRE']; ?>">
```

es lo mismo para los demas campos. Por cierto, en tu archivo modificar-buque.php, que necesidad hay de esto?

```
$v1 =$_GET['id'];
$v2 = $v1;
```

con la primera linea es suficiente.

Y otra cosa **IMPORTANTE**, veo que ocupas sentencias como

```
mysql_query....
```

eso ya no se ocupa, lo que estas haciendo esta defasado. Ocupa POO o bien mysqli. puedes encontrar información aquí en el foro o bien en la pagina oficial de PHP: [manual mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php/)

Salu2.